# Dealing with overlapping numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

My program takes a pair of numbers and subtracts them from one another then adds all the differences from the pairs back up for a total.

My problem is that some of the numbers overlap, by numbers I am using start and end times. I need to find a way to disregard overlapping numbers so that an input of

```
{{10, 14}, {4, 18}, {19, 20}, {19, 20}, {13, 20}
```

returns a total of `16` and not `27`. Thus far I have created another array called hours to check off times already existing. Here is that portion of code:

```
public static int monitoring(int[][] intervals) {
    int sum = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    boolean[] hours = new boolean[24];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        end = intervals[i][1];
        start = intervals[i][0];    
        for(int j = start; j < end; j++) {
            hours[j] = true;
            count++;
        sum += end - start;
        }
    }

    return sum;
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "overlapping numbers" as it is unclear what is meant by that.

Comment: Why is this returning 16?  Which pairs are used?

Comment: I think is a typo on the `OP` probably he meant `26`

Comment: No, it seems that this is the number of hours in a day covered by the union of the intervals.

Comment: By overlapping, I mean for example {10,14} and {4,18} are overlapping since {4,18} would cover {10,14}. 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what you are reaaly trying to get, 2 options possible:

1. you are probably trying to get difference between maximum of the
   2nd element if pairs, and minimum of the 1st element in pairs
2. you want to count numbers of unique "points" (or hours) in given
   interval list.

Simplest solution can be:

```
            if (!hours[j]) {
                hours[j] = true;
                count++;
            }
```

In this case you do not even need "sum" variable.

Comment: I suggest a revision in your answer. Think of the case `{{4,8},{14,16}}`. I believe the OP wants the result to be 6, which is not `16-4`. Your code will give the correct result, but your text is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I found adding another for loop such as: for(int x = 0; x < hours.length; x++){ if(hours[x]){ sum++; } } takes care of the problem.